# Turning varchar into set

Tags: mysql, sql

I've inherited a DB with about 6,000 entries.  One of the columns represents a set of 6 items as varchar.  Some of the entries look like this:

```
A
ABC
A,B,C,D,E,F
ade
ONONONONONONON
onon?" or sleep(10)#onononon
```

It looks pretty trashy but I'm thinking I want to salvage the ones that are represented as letters, but ignore what looks like the result of an injection attack.

What I want to do is represent this column as a SET type.  I'm thinking along the lines of (pseudocode):

```
UPDATE MYTABLE 
SET NEWCOLUMN = (NEWCOLUMN & 'A') 
WHERE (REGEX MATCHES OLDCOLUMN)
```

And repeat this query 6 times for the 6 different elements.

I can't figure out my next step though... I can't seem to figure out how to write this update query so that it works -- to begin with, I can't seem to figure out how to write a regex for mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, your best bet will be to run it through a scripting language like PHP, Perl, Python, etc... and break out the values into new records that way.  A single SQL query won't be up to the task.

Answer (score 0):

While this solution doesn't involve sql, you might find it useful. Try using Google Refine, it's a free tool for cleaning-up heterogenous datasets, it has a nice gui and allows you to use regular expressions, etc.

Comment: While that looks like an interesting tool I cannot place this data on Google's servers.

Answer (score 0):

I only quickly tested this but how about ALTER TABLE

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn SET('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'A', 'C');
```

I'd do this on a copy first and make sure there are no warnings or you will lose data.